# Xcode 4.3 with Eclipse, CUDA, problems?

Tags: xcode, eclipse, macos, cuda

I understand that the /Developer folder no longer exists after installing XCode4.3. To me, this seems it would have bad consequences. First, CUDA installs into /Developer/GPU_Computing. Second, what happens to the GCC keychain? Eclipse relies on the GCC keychain command line tools, which I'm told disappear with Xcode 4.3.

Can someone shed light as to whether they have dealt with either of these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4.3 changed a lot.
Starting from the version 4.3 XCode became a standard Mac OS X application(it reside in the Application Folder),  so you can try to move the GPU_Computing under the new root folder of XCode. However i think that an updated version of the CUDA SDK you add support for the new Xcode folder structure.

XCode and Apple are moving towards the new [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) compiler, so GCC still supported for now, but it will disappear in next releases, so you should migrate to LLVM as soon as you can ...

You can still use GCC with eclipse installing [Command line Developer Tools package](http://rys.sommefeldt.com/2012/02/22/OS-X-command-line-tools.html) .

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install command-line tools package.

Run Xcode, open Wcode->Preferences..., and on "Components" tab on the "Downloads" screen select "Command line tools".

I can build and run CUDA Toolkit samples with that package installed.